# How to check amount sent with transaction (like msg.value>6 in ethereum)

Tags: transactions, contract, ligo

How do I check inside a contract entrypoint, that the user sent a particular amount with the transaction? In Frontend:

`const operation = await contractInstance.methods.methodName().send({amount:12});`

How do I check inside contract (CameLIGO syntax)that parameter **amount** is greater than a particular value inside my LIGO contract(CameLIGO syntax)?

I only want user to able to complete contract call if he sends above a particular amount with transaction else transaction fails.

Answer (score 0):

It is done using **Tezos.amount**
 `if Tezos.amount >= someValue then performSomething() else doSomethingElse()`

Link to Documentation [https://ligolang.org/docs/reference/current-reference/]